# Renting a windows 7/10/Server machine for a few hours

Tags: windows, hosting, cloud

Allow me to describe the need for this server:

I do some 3D modelling and rendering as a freelancer and the rendering engine I use, uses the CPU's power to produce the renderings. The current machine I use for these renderings is a windows 10/64-bit with an i7 3rd gen. When I start rendering the machine becomes basically unusable so I am looking into the possibility of renting a server for a few hours, spin it up do my renderings and kill it and thus I only want to pay for the time/power I use.

Therefore I need a way to have some sort of virtual machine that I can turn on and have the rendering engine all set and configured ready to render, so I don't have to install and setup every time.

As requirements I just need a windows machine OS must be Windows 10. I need lots of CPU power and a modest amount of RAM.

Do you know any service that could offer me something like that?

Thanks

Comment: `Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly.` - flagging to close the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft's Azuer comes to mind, although you'll have similar service with Amazon, with Azure you'll be able to spin a Windows Server 2016 vm in just a couple of clicks and pay only for the time the machine is up. I know you asked for Windows 10, but there isn't any templates to automatically configure a vm with Windows 10 in Azure, although I'm sure it's possible to do, it would be much easier with Windows Server using their templates and your rendering software shouldn't have any issues working with Windows Server.